# Testing a state machine saga in MassTransit with a Kafka rider

Tags: testing, masstransit, saga

In MassTransit documentation, I saw an example of testing a state machine saga with a bus, but there was no example of doing it with a Kafka rider. Whether you do it the same way, or should it be done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no test harnesses for riders, only for the supported transports.

You can look at the state machine unit tests for Kafka in the [unit tests](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.KafkaIntegration.Tests/Producer_Specs.cs#L109) project.